# How to process Postgres database with Hadoop in realtime?

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, bigdata

I have a Postgres database used in production server which need to be analysed regularly using Hadoop. Every queries made in Hadoop should be based on the latest possible version in Postges database. Out of sync is acceptable, but should only for a few minutes delay.

How to do this nearly-realtime data analytics in Hadoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be achieved by configuring the [Storage Handler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StorageHandlers) API  implementation of Hive.

The concept of Storage Handler is just to have the external table metadata alone in the Hive metastore and the actual data storage system will be external data sources. Wherein the hive table meta data will contain the details of the external database table with the usual column and format details.

Whenever you write data to the Hive table which is configured with storage handler, then the storage hanlder API will delegate the write operation to the external database configured so that the records will be written to the external table.

In the Same way when you read data from Hive table configured with the storage handler, then the actual records will be fetched from the external table by the API.

It seems there is already an Hive storage handler api implementation for postgres database was available, please refer the below url.

https://github.com/myui/HiveJdbcStorageHandler

Hope this helps you..